# Gulp: Object #<Object> has no method 'if'

Tags: gulp, gulp-if

I have cloned a repo with a working gulpfile.js, and now when running gulf on the cloned repo, I received the error

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'if'
```

The offending task code:
    gulp.task('html', ['styles'], function () {

```
return gulp.src('app/*.html')
  .pipe($.useref.assets({searchPath: '{.tmp,app}'}))
  .pipe($.if('*.css', $.csso()))
  .pipe($.useref.restore())
  .pipe($.useref())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

I have installed gulp-if and gulp-csso. $ is

```
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
```

Still learning gulp. Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

In **package.json**, *gulp-if* was not listed under devDependencies.

```
  "devDependencies": {
      .
      .
      .
      "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
```

Including it eliminated the error.

Whenever installing a development dependency, I should affix --save-dev so the package is automatically placed in package.json, and then anyone cloning will automatically get all the packages in package.json by issuing the npm install command.

```
npm install <package> --save-dev
```